# Window command prompt Stuck

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I am running a jar file using batch file. Jar file functionality is to take data from database table using web service and call other web service to insert data into database, this task repeats after 5 mints. Data which we are transferring contains string and images. Problem we are facing is cmd hangs after one hour and stop sending data but when we stop and run the batch file again it sends data.
Any suggestions to improve this solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you close and restart your InputStream or any data sockets after use? They may had expired and would not be responding.

```
.close();  // then...
.connect();
```

should be good enough.

Comment: When you restart the program, the Sockets are been re-initiated, so they will work, I think! Output Stream as well!